# No EAR to Deploy

Tags: eclipse, websphere, maven-plugin, rad

After importing existing Maven projects to the Eclipse workspace attempts to deploy an EAR to the WebSphere fails with error that no resources found that can be deployed.

I found out that one of the projects that had "Dynamic Web Module" facet became  "Utility Module" in Eclipse.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using maven-eclipse-plugin to import the project into Eclipse, then you need to [enable the WTP support](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/wtp.html).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing "Maven Integration for WTP".